# Instanceof a factory function is not an instance

Tags: javascript

```
var Car = function(name){
    var name = name;

    function test(){
        console.log(name);
    }

    return{
        test
    }
}

var myCar = Car("a");
console.log(myCar instanceof Car); // false
```

Why myCar instanceof Car its returning false? What should i do make it return true using factory functions?

Answer (score 0):

> Why myCar instanceof Car its returning false?

`myCar instanceof Car` works by checking whether `Car.prototype` is in the prototype chain of `myCar`.

But since `Car` returns an object literal, `Car.prototype` is not in that object's prototype chain, and therefore `instanceof` returns `false`.

> What should i do make it return true using factory functions?

Nothing. If you want `instanceof` to work then you have to use the function as a constructor function (i.e. don't return anything from the function and call it with `new Car()`).

I'd argue that instances returned by a *factory* function should not be considered instances of that function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the 'new' keyword when creating the object. I've put some code below with a couple of fixes which means you don't need to return anything in the parent.

```
var Car = function(name){
  this.name = name;

  function test(){
      console.log(name);
  }
}
var myCar = new Car('hello');
console.log(myCar.name); // Now returns 'hello'
console.log(myCar instanceOf Car) // Returns true
```